# How to find the jdbc driver version of DB2 in our project?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, jdbc, db2

I can only find the version of db2jcc4 in pom.xml, which is 10.1.
How can I know the version of JDBC driver that the db2jcc4 is using?
BTW, I did not install db2 in my computer. It's a remote database.

Comment: [Search thoroughly](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=get+version+of+jdbc+driver+site%3Astackoverflow.com&t=ipad&ia=web) before posting here.

Comment: You can get the JDBC driver version from the JDBC connection. Get the DatabaseMetaData object and then: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getDriverVersion--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java -cp ./db2jcc4.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version
```